# Cron expr for 5th working day

Tags: jakarta-ee

IN general cron we can find the 5th day of every month by using " 0 15 9 5 * ? 2011 " this expression but to find the 5th working day how do i go on, i have idea like first we need to create the list of holidays then we need to write the condition based on that, So can anybody tell me, like if i'm in right track or any other way pls let me know using Java code.

Hi I want to generate the 5th working day of every month using Java like the above expression which is for 5th day of every month

Comment: To you want Java code or a cron expression?

Answer (score 0):

This for instance in Java will generate a `Date` at 9:15 AM for the 5th of every month in 2011:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Wed Jan 05 09:15:00 PST 2011
Sat Feb 05 09:15:00 PST 2011
Sat Mar 05 09:15:00 PST 2011
Tue Apr 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Thu May 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Sun Jun 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Tue Jul 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Fri Aug 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Mon Sep 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Wed Oct 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Sat Nov 05 09:15:00 PDT 2011
Mon Dec 05 09:15:00 PST 2011
```

You might want to take a look at the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) library for Java. It supports cron expressions for triggering jobs in Java.